# Imaginary worlds - Challenge #4

Tags: discussion, contest

## Contest: Imaginary worlds

This is your opportunity to depart from reality a little. The goal of this competition is to spark your imagination and creativity, and to be a fun departure from more 'serious' works.

**Objective: Create an imaginary world using non-photorealistic rendering techniques**

You can use any method you want (i.e. Freestyle, Low-Poly, Texture Paint, etc.), as long as you use Blender for all modelling and rendering. Both Blender Internal and Cycles render engines may be used. Minor post processing in 2D photo editing programs is permitted.

---

**Rules:**

- Only *new and original* work.
- Blender only, non commercial add-ons are allowed.
- Keep it nice, nothing you wouldn't want to show to a five year old.
- If any doubt is raised about the validity of your entry, you will be required to show a .blend file, so we can be sure it is yours (use pasteall.org). Otherwise your entry will be disqualified.
- The competition runs for approximately 1 week, you can edit/change your submission at anytime
- Late entries will be disqualified
- Only one entry per person (*Multiple images of the same entry are allowed*)
- Downvotes will not be considered when picking the winner

---

**Voting guide:**

<sup>(Going beyond the simple visual appeal)</sup>

1. **Creative:** Shows thought and artistry

   - Appealing, good story-telling
   - Artistically carried out, high quality result
2. Meets objective, not missing anything
3. No rules were broken
4. Artistically sound:

   - Good composition
   - Good use of color
   - Solid design
5. Well Executed

   - Technically impressive
   - Quality of execution meets artistic goals.
6. Judge all included images on all of these points.

---

**Winning criteria:** 
Submission with the **most upvotes** as of January 23<sup>rd</sup> 2015 (UTC +0000). The submission must to be posted before the deadline.

**Deadline for entries: January 19<sup>th</sup> 2015 at UTC +0000**
**Voting ends: January 23<sup>rd</sup> 2015 at UTC +0000**

## And most importantly, have fun!

*If you have any questions, ask them in the [events chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18173/events).*

---

## PGMath [4 votes] has won the competition, congratulations!

Notice that changes to the competition structure are under discussion, so new ones may not show up in the near future. Check out the [**Events chat room**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18173/events) to keep up with the discussion.

Also see [**this proposal on Meta**](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/591/new-contest-format-proposal).

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to render the really odd perspective on my render.

Comment: @VinceScalia Odd perspective? The small planets are modeled that way, even in my render(made before the comp) I used a sphere for the surface.

Comment: Have you ever seen MC Eschers *other world*? that's the perspective.

Comment: If not see [this](http://www.mcescher.com/gallery/back-in-holland/other-world/) One of the best sites ever.

Comment: @VinceScalia Try messing around with the Camera's focal length.

Comment: PGMath has 8 votes now!

Comment: PGMath has 9 votes now!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is pretty slapped together, slipshod scene :D but [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhXvu.jpg) is my render.

[image]

I think about 60% of the time I spent on this was modeling the Statue of Liberty, I then realized I only had 2 days left and slapped the rest of the scene together!

Comment: I think you win, nobody else entered . . .

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I think we definitely need to advertise these challenges more.  And I think a week is kind of short for a lot of people, especially since a lot of people on this site (like myself) are just hobbyists, this isn't our job (I'm still in high school).  My entry, as you can probably see, is super slipshod (looking at it now I think the best part is the Saturn shader :P).  I should just make Saturn the whole scene!  But anyhow I think a couple of weeks should be a minimum.  As long as we advertise it well to begin with (and don't have it over Christmas break) I think people will...

Comment: ...not forget about it if they start working on it.

Comment: Name your image!

Comment: @PGmath you should make a repeatable GIF of earth rotating. That way we could see the great wall of china!

Comment: @PGmath You won! Yay! XD