# Featured image contest revisited

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

[We've discussed](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/591/599) having a [photo.se style continuous contest](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657/36826) to provide a "featured render" for display on the main site before, but now that we are graduating it's time to see about making this happen.

Basically everyone who wants to enter would post their render on a massive meta thread, then every so often the highest voted entry would be displayed on the main site. Once it's had it's turn, the entry would go into a "hall of fame" meta post, making way for new renders to become the highest voted. The idea is to have a very relaxed "contest" that anyone can participate in without having to worry about a boatload of rules and restrictions. As a bonus, we get fresh pretty artwork on the front of the site on a regular basis :)

How can we work this idea into the design of the site? What kind of special considerations can we have implemented to streamline the operation of this contest? E.g. automated ways to feature and move posts to a hall of fame on a fixed interval (perhaps with a way to adjust the interval, so we can speed up the turnover a little once more people participate).

Comment: Should there be a minimum reputation, say 300, to encourage people to not just use BSE as a place to park their fantastic work for a week, and instead also contribute to the information we have on the site. 300 is an arbitrary value, but there should be some threshold..

Comment: @zeffii I would say no. I think most (if not all) blender users who find the contest will likely participate in the main site at least a little bit. However *enforcing* participation is not a good idea imo, if anything that will discourage potential new users from having anything to do with us. They'll perceive the site as an "exclusive club" where only the privileged high-rep users are allowed. We want to welcome all contributions, large and small.

Comment: 300 points is not high rep, and I think it's reasonable to encourage people to participate at least a little bit to share their knowledge. If they're any good they'll easily gain rep. I don't want to see just any render in the header, it has to be quality, it is supposed to be promotional material after all. If we set the threshold at 7000k. yeah that would be "elitism ".

Comment: @zeffii Well, the entries that go into the header will be selected by voting. Presumably "bad" entries will not get many votes.

Comment: Seems a little inconsistent to not require reputation for the privilege of getting work up there. I have no doubt we'll vote for the good stuff. I just like the idea that those who do get their work up there have spent a little time sharing their knowledge on this site. As it stands there are already many ways to share epic work (BA, Blendernation...etc)  -- I won't harp on about this, if it's just me that feels this way..

Comment: @zeffii It's a good point, and one which should be decided by the community. You might consider writing an answer here so people can vote on the idea :)

Answer (score 2):

Downvote if you don't agree, else upvote!

---

Assuming we get this feature, why not vote on 1 particular facet of the proposal.

> namely: Besides votes for the Artwork, do we also demand a minimum reputation threshold?

I propose 300 points. Why? Because it encourages people to participate in the main site, and it's not that high that it could be mistaken for elitism.

Our collective votes will probably already filter the good stuff anyway. no matter if you have 6000 points, if your art isn't display quality (why?) would we want it up there?

But if someone just joins to show their Blender work, and doesn't participate "on the front lines" like every one us, then I see that as a disconnect and even inconsistency with the reputation system, where privilege is earned. If they're good it will shine through how they answer questions way before submitting artwork. If they really want to get their work up there 300 points shouldn't take too long.

The vote will be for a threshold of some kind, if you think 300 is too high, add a comment with how much. ( 50, 100, 150... etc).

Comment: 300 is wayyyy too high. 125 rep, at least twenty-five days on the site, and ten days where a user has asked a question. I know that sounds a wee bit over-complicated, but it'll help weed out the people that are truly new and/or are only good at troubleshooting.

Comment: yeah, maybe 125 is enough, but how fast they reach that is less relevant to me. At any rate all I would like to persuade is the idea that we attach some importance to site-participation, there are after-all already many ways for people to share their work and promote Blender outside of BSE.

Comment: The rep threshold will most definitely need to be tweaked. Other than that, I really like this idea :)

Comment: I voted down, but if there is a threshold - remember that users coming from other SE sites automatically start with 101 rep